# using webpack 2 DefinePlugin with angular-cli based project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-2

I'm trying to convert an angular2 with webpack2 project to angular-cli based project.

if I understood correctly, angular-cli now supports webpack. in my original project I injected the following `app.config.js`:

```
module.exports =  {
    webServer: {
        appBaseHref : JSON.stringify("/")
    },
    auth0: {
        apiKey: JSON.stringify("API_KEY"),
        domain: JSON.stringify("DOMAIN.auth0.com"),
        callbackUrl: JSON.stringify("CALLBACK_URL")
    }
};
```

by adding the following to `webpack.config.js`  file:

```
const appConfig = require("./config/app.config");
const DefinePlugin = require("webpack/lib/DefinePlugin");
...
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
       new DefinePlugin({
           APP_CONFIG: appConfig
       }),
...
```

then in my typescript project i would declare APP_CONFIG with `declare var APP_CONFIG:any;` and then I would use it's properties. how can I inject such an object in an angular-cli project?

thanks

Comment: Can't you just make a service for this?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz - yes.. I can.. trying to figure out why I did it with webpack in the first place but i got nothing :) what do I do ? do you want to post it as an answer? do I delete this question ?

Comment: Gimme a minute.

Comment: So I want this same thing - so that I can inject the build numbers.  Not sure the service answer will work for me.  I would like to have a global like APP_VERSION and set it to `childProcess.execSync('git rev-list HEAD --count').toString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example that just uses a normal service with a `set` and `get` method:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class AppConfigService {

  public config: any = {
    apiKey: '[api_key]',
    domain: '[domain]',
    callbackUrl: '[callbackUrl]'
  }

  constructor() {}

  /* Allows you to update any of the values dynamically */
  set(k: string, v: any): void {
    this.config[k] = v;
  }

  /* Returns the entire config object or just one value if key is provided */
  get(k: string): any {
    return k ? this.config[k] : this.config;
  }
}
```

For more complex use cases you might want to convert it to an observable instead but I don't see that being necessary in this simple case.